# csrf cookie not set django

Tags: python, django, cookies

I have some problem for a while now, I'm experiencing CSRF Cookie not set. Please look at the codes below

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
def login_user(request):
    state = "Please log in below..."
    username = password = ''
    dic = {}
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
        dic['state'] = state
        dic['username'] = username
        dic.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('authen/auth.html',dic )
```

templates(authen.html)

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Log in</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
body{
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    {{ state }}
    <form action="/login/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% if next %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        {% endif %}
        username: 
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username}}" /><br />
        password:
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </form>
</body>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from . import views

     urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', views.login_user),
      ]
```

setting.py

```
  INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'authen')
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'Auth.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.csrf'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Auth.wsgi.application'
```

Im stuck, I already cleared the cookie, used other browser but still csrf cookie not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manually adding the CSRF token to the context, but you are only doing it *after* the POST. The whole point of a CSRF token is that it is set by the GET, and checked on POST. Since you are not setting it on GET, the POST will fail.

However you **should not** be setting it manually at all. Django will do it for you, as long as you use a RequestContext. And the way to do that is to use the `render` shortcut, passing it the request, rather than the old `render_to_response`.

Remove the call to `csrf(request)` and replace your last line with:

```
return render(request, 'authen/auth.html', dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view.py add RequestContext(request) to render_to_response:

```
return render_to_response('authen/auth.html',dic, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the Forbidden (403), CSRF cookie not set. error.  I thought it had something to do with ios.

I fixed this by adding an "s" to the end of http, FROM: htt**p:**//MYAPPNAME.herokuapp.com/ TO: htt**ps:**//MYAPPNAME.herokuapp.com/

In

```
# settings.py
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```